# PHP -- SimpleXMLElement -- parsing im:image

Tags: php, simplexml, xml-namespaces

How do I extract im:image elements.  For instance, I can do this:

```
$feed=file_get_contents($url);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($feed);
$title = $xml->entry[0]->title;
$html = $xml->entry[0]->content;
```

But I can't get this:

```
$img = $xml->entry[0]->im;
```

How do I target those?  I'm willing to use DOMDocument() as well.

EDIT:

```
<entry>
  <im:image height="55">
    http://foo.com/foo.jpg
  </im:image>
</entry>
```

Comment: And your XML is.... rss?

Comment: The im is just a namespace. You want 'image' element, not im

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, that was the clue I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The im is just a namespace. You want 'image' element, not im – Dmitri Snytkine 20 hours ago

Yes, that's true, and the clue I needed.